# JQuery AJAX HTML response in error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
var id = 45;        
$.ajax({
            url :'url', // This URL response some HTML content
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data :{ID:id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data); // No Response here
            },
            error : function (error){
                console.log(error); // error.responseText contain html content
            }
        });
```

I render HTML content by JQuery AJAX. The HTML response comes from error function instead of success function. is any mistake from my side?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: which server side technology you are using?

Comment: if you are returning `html` from server then instead of `dataType: 'json'` use `dataType: 'html'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use html instead of json for datatype
>
> The datatype property specifies the type of data that you're expecting
>   back from the server

```
$.ajax({
                url :'url', // This URL response some HTML content
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data :{ID:id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data); // No Response here
                },
                error : function (error){
                    console.log(error); // error.responseText contain html content
                }
            });
```

See the [Jquery Api for more details](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't get your question ?

Comment: i think Ramesh Murugesan know already that the result is an HTML content :)

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Thanks mate.. It works :) dataType should be in html.